# How to install Qt4 and Qt5 alongside each other Ubuntu 1804

Tags: qt

I have some software packages that depend on qt4. I installed Qt 4 just for those packages with the command `sudo apt install qt4-default`. I want to install `qt5-default`, but when I run the command `sudo apt install qt5-default`, the `apt` package manager then reports to me that it will uninstall everything to do with `qt4`.

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-dev libqt4-dev-bin libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-opengl-dev libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql
  libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtdbus4 libqtgui4 qdbus qt-at-spi qt4-linguist-tools qt4-qmake qtcore4-l10n
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

What do I do to get both software versions to install on the same machine?

Comment: I recommend you post your question in https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: qt4-default and qt5-default are developer packages. There can be only 1 default. You probably don't want them to just run software. Anyway, just install the packages you need separately.

Comment: What do you mean by `just install the packages you need separately` @hyde? I would assume that the library files are not the same, so they should not have intersecting paths. I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean, `apt install libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-dev libqt4-dev-bin libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-opengl-dev libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql
  libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtdbus4 libqtgui4 qdbus qt-at-spi qt4-linguist-tools qt4-qmake qtcore4-l10n` if you want all those packages. Or just install the packages actually needed by your SW. Probably remove at least the dev packages from the list.

Comment: Oh, so you are saying that `qt4-default` is a meta package for those packages you list above? How do you get that list of dependencies/sub-packages of `qt4-default`? Trying to copy paste that list from SO might be problematic I tried `apt-cache rdepends qt4-default` but that keeps returning `qt5-default`. If I can get all of the dependencies for `qt5-default` as well, then that should be straight forward.